# Play a WAV file on Symbian with Qt (QSound)

Tags: qt, audio, symbian, wav, playback

I'm trying to play a [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file in [Symbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian) using Qt Creator.

I got this:

```
QSound::play("c:/notify.wav");
```

It works on Windows, but when I try it on Symbian it doesn't make a sound, but no error though.

This is most likely because it doesn't find the file (no `notify.wav` file under C:)

How can I include a WAV file so it gets installed to the Symbian device and so I can use its path to play it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DEPLOYMENT qmake instruction in your .pro file
e.g:

```
symbian{
sounds.sources = path to your wav
sounds.path = ./thewav.wav
DEPLOYMENT += sounds
}
```

This will deploy the wav in your app's directory. QSound::play("notify.wav") should work then, if not try to get the path to your directory from QApplication.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it worked.

This is what I did:

In the `.pro` file:

```
symbian: {
    sounds.sources = c:/notify.wav
    sounds.path = c:/
    DEPLOYMENT += sounds
}
```

In the program:

```
QSound::play("c:/notify.wav");
```

This way it works in Windows and in Symbian.